# Is it not possible for a daemon to turn off the X11 screensaved using DBus?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, x11, dbus, screensaver

I'm creating a tool on an embedded system and I wanted to inhibit the screensaver using the DBus mechanism.

This works perfectly when I test my app. on my computer. I can check with the following command:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager \
          /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.GetInhibitors
```

and I can see my app. in the array.

However, when I run the exact same application as a daemon, it connects to the DBus session properly, but when I try to send the message to inhibit the screensaver, I don't get a reply at all. DBus generates an error like so:

> *The name org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver was not provided by any .service files*

Ultimately, the daemons will run as its own user (like Apache2 runs as www under Ubuntu).

Is that just not possible? Can only the currently logged in user tweak the ScreenSaver in this way? Or could I somehow authorize the daemon user who then could access the ScreenSaver parameter?

Comment: Why not run the daemon as user?

Comment: @stark Yes. That would be my next best bet. One reason, though, is the security. The daemon's user doesn't have a shell and very minimal permissions outside of its own folders & files.

Comment: If it's not the owner of the Xsession, it won't be able to make changes unless it uses the xauth mechanisms.